# Unknown column in 'field list' on inner join

Tags: mysql

Hi I am not so experience with SQL and try to make this query work

```
select ad.ad_id as the_ad_id
     , ad_country.country_id
     , v.vertical
  from ad 
  left 
  join ad_country 
    on ad.ad_id = ad_country.ad_id 
  join 
     ( select ad_id 
         from ad_vertical 
        where ad_vertical.vertical = 'biz op'
     ) as v 
    on ad.ad_id = v.ad_id 
 limit 10
```

And I get the error:

> Unknown column 'v.vertical' in 'field list

But when I'm the same query with left join without filtering it is working.

```
select ad.ad_id as the_ad_id
     , ad_country.country_id
     , v.vertical
  from ad 
  left 
  join ad_country 
    on ad.ad_id = ad_country.ad_id 
  left 
  join ad_vertical as v 
    on ad.ad_id = v.ad_id 
 limit 10
```

Can you help me figure out what am I doing wrong?
Thanks
, Or

Comment: Note that LIMIT without ORDER BY is fairly meaningless

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first query, `v` is an alias for nested query:

```
inner join 
  (select `ad_id` from `ad_vertical` where `ad_vertical`.`vertical` = 'biz op') 
as `v`
```

... which doesn't have column `vertical`. In your second query, however, `v` is an alias for the whole `ad_vertical` table.

Comment: Oh wow I feel kinda stupid. It's make sense. Just trying to learn it in like two days and get a bit confused. 
Thank you kind sir

Answer (score 1):

> ```sql
> [...]
> inner join (select `ad_id` from `ad_vertical` where `ad_vertical`.`vertical` = 'biz op') 
> as `v`
> ```

You are only selecting the column `ad_id` from the `ad_vertical` table. Your alias `v` will therefore only have that column `ad_id`. This means that you cannot use `v.vertical` in your outer `SELECT` query.

If you want to return the `vertical` column as well you have you adjust the `INNER JOIN` query to return it as well:

```sql
[...]
inner join (select `ad_id`, `vertical` from `ad_vertical` where `ad_vertical`.`vertical` = 'biz op') 
as `v`
```